# My ipython console is not working

Tags: python, ipython, anaconda, spyder

Whenever i try to print something my ipython console doesn't work but my python console is working fine please help.How to fix this?

[Here is the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BxXcc.png)

Comment: Please run `spyder --reset && spyder --default`in bash

Comment: I tried its still not working :(